# Using external library in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to upload image in my iOS app. I am using Swift.

I have found [this library](https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient), but I can't see any information explaining how to use this library in my project. Could somebody tell me how to install this library in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Download the files you need (in this case, `SRWebClient\SRWebClient.h` and `SRWebClient\SRWebClient.swift`

Step 2: Add those files to your project.

You should be good after that.